# Having effect of java/jsp changes without restarting tomcat

Tags: tomcat, myeclipse, hotdeploy

How should I configure tomcat so that JSP/Java changes are in effect immediately without restarting the tomcat? When I redeploy the app after making some Java changes it restarts the tomcat automatically. This is really frustrating because tomcat takes 3-4 minutes to start for my web app.

I am using Version: 6.5.1 GA,Apache Tomcat 6.0

Thank you.

Comment: It is a feature of Tomcat called autoDeploy that does this,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse , this should be easy . In eclipse as soon as you change something and save that change eclipse will update the deployment automatically in a manner of 3-4 seconds .

We are doing this all the time and it works perfectly. Only thing is you cannot build your app via ant or maven. In eclipse you have an option to right click and say "run on server" from the "Run As" menu . I think this should suffice your need for development.

We only use ant scripts for deploying to staging or production , and for development we use the above mentioned solution

Comment: Any particular version of eclipse I should download? I will download that.

Comment: You can download the latest version of eclipse. You need to download eclipse for j2ee.